# Dlink 600l cloud router not working

Tags: router, wifi-configuration

I have a D-Link DIR-600L router that does not seem to be working as it is supposed to. Every time I try to configure the router, after all the settings have been saved as in the ssid and password etc, I do not see the 'configure' button at the bottom of the last page which redirects to Mydlink account settings. Instead of that I see a 'setting' button which does not work. I am unable to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Use different browsers like Chrome / Mozilla etc. to access the router config pages and see if that makes any difference.
2. Do a factory hard reset (By pressing the reset button for 10 to 15 seconds) and let the router restart and initiate with default settings. Then manually reconfigure all settings and check if it works.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for trying to help on this question.  Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase, and the Q&A format relies on answers being definitive solutions to the question.  Helpful hints and speculative solutions can be posted as a comment, which requires a little more rep.  If the questioner indicates that it solved the problem, you can repost it as an answer.